# ajax get call is not working? it show the error not ajax call not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-routing

Dear i have an ajax call in my edit page in laravel  where i want to get indicators from a function here is my ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var id = $('#activity').val();
     
     ajaxcall= $.ajax({
        url: 'editTreeView/'+id,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        
    success: function(response){

        alert(response);

          }});
      });
   </script>
```

it show the following error in my console  GET http://localhost:8000/activity/829a94e7-c282-4830-81fe-e93e1b1e6683/editTreeView/829a94e7-c282-4830-81fe-e93e1b1e6683 404 (Not Found)
where 829a94e7-c282-4830-81fe-e93e1b1e6683 is UUID in laravel i dont know how to send request to the function. any idea please

Comment: Try `url: '/editTreeView/'+id,`  otherwise it's relative to the current page's url, which appears to be `/activity/829a94e7-c282-4830-81fe-e93e1b1e6683`

Comment: i did  url: '/editTreeView/'+id, but same error 404

Answer (score 0):

it works just remove activity from my route Route::get('editTreeView/{id}', 'ActivityController@editTreeView');